# How to identify rows that have the same value in two columns?

Tags: excel, vba, parsing

I'm trying to identify an entire row if column B ***AND*** column C have repeating values with a VBA script. For example if I have a table that contains:

```
ID   Age   Grade
1    14     90
2    15     78
3    14     90
4    16     86
5    16     86
6    15     89
7    14     88
```

After I run the script, I want a new sheet with the rows that have repeating values in column B ***AND*** column C. So the new sheet would look like:

```
ID   Age   Grade
1    14     90
3    14     90
4    16     86
5    16     86
```

This is what I have so far in terms of identifying the rows. I'm not that far along.

```
Sub ID()
Dim LastRowcheck As Long, n1 As Long
Dim LastRowcheck2 As Long, n2 As Long

With Worksheets("grades")
    LastRowcheck = .Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row
    LastRowcheck = .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    For n1 = LastRowcheck To 1 Step -1
        If .Cells(n1, 1).Value = Cells(n1 + 1, 1).Value And .Cells(n2, 1).Value = Cells(n2 + 1, 1).Value Then
           '''export to new sheet
        End If
    Next n1
End With
End Sub
```

Comment: First you should sort the columns by age and then grade in ascending order  then you can check consecutive rows to see if they have same values, and then once you've pruned the table you can resort by ID

Comment: the sheet i'm working with is over 100,000 rows and not all grades are whole numbers, they go as far as 3 decimal places. it'd be much easier to identify them through a script. @AhmedMasud

Comment: Use `application.countifs` to identify multiples.

Comment: @Jeeped how would i go about using that?

Comment: My suggestion is independent of the row-count and of the grades being in floating point format (you should be using numeric sorts).

Comment: countifs will not be an easy nor an efficient solution

Comment: @AhmedMasud - If efficiency is of prime concern then all processing should be performed within a 2-D variant memory array. My suggestion was tailored to the OP's expertise. Sometimes you need to learn to walk before running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `application.countifs` to identify multiples.

```
Dim lastRowcheck As Long, n1  As Long

With Worksheets("grades")
    lastRowcheck = Application.Max(.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, _
                                   .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For n1 = lastRowcheck To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountIfs(.Columns("B"), .Cells(n1, "B").Value2, .Columns("C"), .Cells(n1, "C").Value2) > 1 Then
           '''export to new sheet
           Debug.Print .Cells(n1, "A") & ":" & .Cells(n1, "B") & ":" & .Cells(n1, "C")
        End If
    Next n1
End With
```

Comment: I got an "Application defined or object defined error" with the If statement. any ideas?

Comment: My apologies; I had the wrong var name. Fixed above.

Comment: is this supposed to output to a new sheet as well or does it just identify the rows?

Comment: It identifies (and writes to the VBE's Immediate window) the duplications in columns B & C. I'm not going to start making up imaginary destination worksheets and code all of that for you. That was not the question posed in this query. If that is what you are looking for, get started and post another question asking for assistance when you run into trouble.