# How to export identified values to a new sheet?

Tags: vba, excel

This is a follow up to my previous question that can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43500990/how-to-identify-rows-that-have-the-same-value-in-two-columns)

Just for a quick recap, I have this table:

```
ID  Age Grade
1   14  90
2   15  78
3   14  90
4   16  86
5   16  86
6   15  89
7   14  88
```

My desired output table in a new sheet is:

```
ID  Age Grade
1   14  90
3   14  90
4   16  86
5   16  86
```

I went through and picked out the rows that have repeating values in column B ***AND*** column C using this:

```
Sub Export()

Dim lastRowcheck As Long, n1  As Long

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRowcheck = Application.Max(.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, _
                                   .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For n1 = lastRowcheck To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountIfs(.Columns("B"), .Cells(n1, "B").Value2, .Columns("C"), .Cells(n1, "C").Value2) > 1 Then
           Debug.Print .Cells(n1, "A") & ":" & .Cells(n1, "B") & ":" & .Cells(n1, "C")
           '''export to new sheet
        End If
    Next n1
End With

End Sub
```

Now I just need to figure out how to export those rows into a new sheet and I have no idea where to start.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Updated your code to show how to export the found rows to a new sheet:

```
Sub Export()

Dim lastRowcheck As Long, n1  As Long
Dim rCopy As Range

With Worksheets("Sheet1")
    lastRowcheck = Application.Max(.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, _
                                   .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)

    For n1 = lastRowcheck To 1 Step -1
        If Application.CountIfs(.Columns("B"), .Cells(n1, "B").Value2, .Columns("C"), .Cells(n1, "C").Value2) > 1 Then
           Debug.Print .Cells(n1, "A") & ":" & .Cells(n1, "B") & ":" & .Cells(n1, "C")
           '''export to new sheet
           If rCopy Is Nothing Then Set rCopy = .Rows(n1) Else Set rCopy = Union(rCopy, .Rows(n1))
        End If
    Next n1
End With


With Sheets("Sheet2")                            'For using a sheet that already exists
'With Sheets.Add(After:=Sheets(Sheets.Count))    'For creating a brand new sheet to use
    If Not rCopy Is Nothing Then rCopy.EntireRow.Copy _
        Destination:=.Cells(.Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Offset(1)
End With

End Sub
```

Comment: this is awesome! exactly what i was looking for. any reason why the column headers didn't make it to the new sheet?

Comment: The column headers weren't identified to be a part of `rCopy`.  You'd need to put a line before the loop adding the header row to `rCopy`

Answer (score 1):

Why you are using loop in descending order

```
For n1 = lastRowcheck To 1 Step -1

For n1 = 1 To lastRowcheck
```

while you can use it if you need result in same order as per data.

```
Sub Export()
Dim lastRowcheck As Long, n1  As Long, i As Long
Dim ws As Worksheet
Set ws = Sheets("NewSheet") 'sheet name to export data
i = 2 'add data from row 2 in new sheet
With Worksheets("Sheet1")
lastRowcheck = Application.Max(.Range("B" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row, _
                               .Range("C" & .Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row)
For n1 = 1 To lastRowcheck
    If Application.CountIfs(.Columns("B"), .Cells(n1, "B").Value2, .Columns("C"), .Cells(n1, "C").Value2) > 1 Then
       Debug.Print .Cells(n1, "A") & ":" & .Cells(n1, "B") & ":" & .Cells(n1, "C")
       '''export to new sheet
       ws.Cells(i, "A") = .Cells(n1, "A")
       ws.Cells(i, "B") = .Cells(n1, "B")
       ws.Cells(i, "C") = .Cells(n1, "C")
       i = i + 1
    End If
Next n1
End With
```

End Sub